# how to get num row where object by other table use codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have 2 tables. Consider tb_burung and tb_data.
This is the structure of tb_burung:

[image]

This is the structure of tb_data: [image: table structure]

I want to get the number of rows of tb_data order id_burung for viewing on a page like this:
[image: output page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but just try following sql:)

```
select t1.burung, count(t2.id_burung) as burungCnt
from tb_burung t1
left join tb_data t2 on t1.id_burung = t2.id_burung
group by t1.id_burung, t1.burung
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all retrieve data from both tables individually. And then loop tb_burung table array and use array_filter out data from tb_data table array according to tb_burung id, use count function to get count of the filtered data. By doing like this, the process will be.

1. Two database query
2. 3 loop, 3 array_filter and 3 count

u got the count.